# compiling C++ program- link error

Tags: c++, compilation, nmake

I'm trying to modify oclvanitygen [[link]](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen), and I've done some of that.  Now I need to test it, but I'm having trouble compiling it on Windows 7.  I'm using the VS Command Prompt in VC++ 2010 Express to run a makefile. The relevant parts of the makefile, as modified by me:

```
CC = cl
OPENSSL_DIR = [Working Dir]\openssl
PTHREADS_DIR = [Working Dir]\pthread
PCRE_DIR = [Working Dir]\pcre
CURL_DIR = C:\curl-7.26.0-x86\builds\libcurl-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi
OPENCL_DIR = [Working Dir]\openCL
OPENCL_INCLUDE = /I$(OPENCL_DIR)\include
OPENCL_LIBS = $(OPENCL_DIR)\OpenCL.lib
CURL_INCLUDE = /I$(CURL_DIR)\include /DCURL_STATICLIB
CURL_LIBS = $(CURL_DIR)\lib\libcurl_a.lib
CFLAGS_BASE = /D_WIN32 /DPTW32_STATIC_LIB /DPCRE_STATIC /I$(OPENSSL_DIR)\inc32 /I$(PTHREADS_DIR) /I$(PCRE_DIR) /Ox /Zi
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS_BASE) /GL
LIBS = $(OPENSSL_DIR)\out32\libeay32.lib $(PTHREADS_DIR)\pthreadVC2.lib $(PCRE_DIR)\pcre.lib ws2_32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib /LTCG /DEBUG 
OBJS = vanitygen.obj oclvanitygen.obj oclengine.obj oclvanityminer.obj keyconv.obj pattern.obj util.obj winglue.obj

all: vanitygen.exe keyconv.exe

vanitygen.exe: vanitygen.obj pattern.obj util.obj winglue.obj
    link /nologo /out:$@ $** $(LIBS)

oclvanitygen.exe: oclvanitygen.obj oclengine.obj pattern.obj util.obj winglue.obj
    link /nologo /out:$@ $** $(LIBS) $(OPENCL_LIBS)

oclvanityminer.exe: oclvanityminer.obj oclengine.obj pattern.obj util.obj winglue.obj
    link /nologo /out:$@ $** $(LIBS) $(OPENCL_LIBS) $(CURL_LIBS)

keyconv.exe: keyconv.obj util.obj winglue.obj
    link /nologo /out:$@ $** $(LIBS)

.c.obj:
    @$(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS) /c /Tp$< /Fo$@

oclengine.obj: oclengine.c
    @$(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS_BASE) $(OPENCL_INCLUDE) /c /Tpoclengine.c /Fo$@

oclvanitygen.obj: oclvanitygen.c
    @$(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS_BASE) /c /Tpoclvanitygen.c /Fo$@

oclvanityminer.obj: oclvanityminer.c
    @$(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS_BASE) $(CURL_INCLUDE) /c /Tpoclvanityminer.c /Fo

clean:
    del vanitygen.exe oclvanitygen.exe oclvanityminer.exe keyconv.exe $(OBJS)
```

Then I use the command

```
nmake /fmakefile.win32 oclvanitygen.exe
```

It fails with the following error:

```
link /nologo /out:oclvanitygen.exe oclvanitygen.obj oclengine.obj pattern.obj util.obj winglue.obj [Working Dir]\openssl\out32\libeay32.lib [Working Dir]\pthread\pthreadVC2.lib [Working Dir]\pcre\pcre.lib ws2_32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib [Working Dir]\openCL\OpenCL.lib /LTCG /DEBUG
LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option ''
NMAKE: fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x45d'
```

What am I doing wrong?  All of the header files and libs are in their correct places.

Comment: Remove the brackets, they are not recognized by the linker. Then try `/VERBOSE`.

Comment: the brackets around "working directory"?  That's just a placeholder for the real path, which is pretty long.  Where do I put the /VERBOSE switch?

Comment: Does "working directory" contain any "/" characters or other non-alphanumerics?